# Spring Integration HttpOutbound throws triggers ErrorChannel when http header ETag: 1 received from the server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

Sorry I Miss understood the problem.

The issue is ETag Header.

This is header response when i make curl request to server.

```
Content-Length: 228
Content-Type: application/json
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 644f1021-bee9-4a11-b8ab-ab8557a746c0-00000f2c
ETag: 1
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID: 0
```

This is StackTrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid ETag: does not start with W/ or "
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.setETag(HttpHeaders.java:1039) ~[spring-web-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.setETag(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:588) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.setHttpHeader(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:406) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:377) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.fromHeaders(DefaultHttpHeaderMapper.java:75) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.setupResponseAndConvertReply(HttpRequestHandlingEndpointSupport.java:427) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest(HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.java:114) ~[spring-integration-http-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1064) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
```

This is my sample code, where service is activated when message is sent to channel 'request.input' if the remote server respond with header ETag: 1 exception is raised.

```
@Value("${auth.token}")
private String authToken;

@Value("${auth.key}")
private String authKey;

@Value("${url}")
private String url;


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outRequest() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/request")
            .requestMapping(m-> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .requestPayloadType(RequestPayloadDTO.class).errorChannel("errorChannel"))
            .transform(requestTransformer)
            .gateway("request.input")
            .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow request() {
    return flow -> flow.enrichHeaders((headerEnricherSpec -> {
        headerEnricherSpec.header(authKey,authToken,true);
    })).handle(Http.outboundGateway(url)
            .mappedRequestHeaders(authKey)
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
            .expectedResponseType(ResponseDTO.class)
    ).transform(responseTransformer);
}


@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "request.input")
public interface RequestGateway {
    ResponseDTO exchange(String out);
}
```

Comment: Show, please, a stack trace which happens in that case. What is an error sent to that `errorChannel`?

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan I have edited the question, I miss understood the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved by adding

```
.transform(responseTransformer).headerFilter("ETag");
```

Thank you.